# How a Viewcontroller identify which test class need to run: Subliminal Framework

Tags: ios, testing, automation, subliminal

I wonder how a `UIViewcontroller` came to know that which test file it needs to pick.

E.g. I have a big project with lots of `UIViewcontrollers` in it.

And I want to make separate test files for each controller. Like 1 for **login**, another for **profile** `UIViewcontroller`.

I know framework is in early stage but any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by **test file** for controller?

Answer (score 4):

In Subliminal, the tests drive your application, not the other way around. You can definitely have tests that correspond to different view controllers, but the tests are responsible for navigating to those controllers' views within the application.

That navigation is generally done within tests' implementations of `-setUpTest`. Let's say that your application opens to a "home" screen, on which there is a button titled "Log in"; and that pressing that button causes a "login view controller" to be presented. The way you'd test that view controller would be to add a test like this to your integration tests target:

```
@interface LoginTest : SLTest
@end

@implementation

- (void)setUpTest {
    // make sure we're at "Home", then:
    SLButton *loginButton = [SLButton elementWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Log in"];
    [loginButton tap];
}

/*
now test the login view controller:
- (void)testThat... { }
*/

- (void)tearDownTest {
    // log out and go back to "Home"
}

@end
```

Note that it's very important that your tests begin and end at known locations, in `-setUpTest` and `-tearDownTest`, respectively--you can't depend on Subliminal tests executing in a particular order.

So how would you test the profile screen, then? Let's say that, in your application, the profile was shown immediately after logging in. Then, a profile test would look something like this:

```
@interface ProfileTest : SLTest
@end

@implementation

- (void)setUpTest {
    // Log in
}

/*
now test the profile view controller:
- (void)testThat... { }
*/

- (void)tearDownTest {
    // log out and go back to "Home"
}

@end
```

You see that `ProfileTest` should do what it needs to get to the view it wants to test--in this case, logging in. (This is why it's important that `LoginTest` logs out and goes back to "home" in `-tearDownTest`, so that `ProfileTest` will start from a known state even if `LoginTest` executes first).

To make this setup process easier, you can use "app hooks". With `LoginTest` verifying that the login UI works, it's not important that `ProfileTest` goes through that UI. Instead, it can ask the application to log in. Right before your application delegate launched the tests, it might register a "login manager" singleton as being able to programmatically log a test user in:

```
[[SLTestController sharedTestController] registerTarget:[LoginManager sharedManager] 
                                           forAction:@selector(logInWithInfo:)];
```

Then, `-[ProfileTest setUpTest]` could call:

```
[[SLTestController sharedTestController] sendAction:@selector(logInWithInfo:)
                                         withObject:@{
                                                        @"username": @"john@foo.com",
                                                        @"password": @"Hello1234"
                                                     }];
```